# Can't add font to QFontDatabase

Tags: python, fonts, pyqt5

I cannot add fonts to QFontDatabase. I'm not making any typos either. The file paths are also correct.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys

class deneme(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.gui()

    def gui(self): 
        
        QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont("Inter-Bold.ttf")
        #print(bool(QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont("Inter-Bold.ttf"))) ---> Returns False

        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText("Merhaba")
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color : black")
        self.label.setFont(QFont("Inter-Bold", 20))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = deneme()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I would be glad if someone could help. [File Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTcNA.png)

Comment: The documentation explains that the function returns -1 if the font is not added. Which obviously means that it could return `0` (which is not strictly *false* in this context) for the first valid font loaded. If the font is not properly displayed, you're probably using the wrong family name. Check the [`applicationFontFamilies()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontdatabase.html#applicationFontFamilies) with the received ID (or use a proper font manager to check that)